# Error in english.cfg

Tags: errors, texlive

I have the following error:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/english.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/germanb.ldf)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/english.ldf
*************************************
* Local config file english.cfg used
*
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/support/pedigree-perl/examples/english.cfg
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode.
l.1 #
      An example configuration file for pedigree program

?
```

Unfortunately, I can not give an minimal example.

This error appeared after I updated to TeX Live 2012/Debian (I am using Linux Mint 14). Before that the documents that now produce the error could be compiled.

I am wondering why this file is looked at at all. Has anyone experienced the same? Or has anyone an idea how to get ride off this error?

Comment: That path should not hashed: I have the same file on my system ('vanilla' TL, Windows 7), but it does not interfere with anything.

Comment: Are you loading anything in relation to `pedigree-perl` in your document? AFAIR usually TL does not load anything from the `doc` three. Besides, it is not a LaTeX file, so it would be nice to figure out why it is loaded in your document. What does `kpdewhich english.cfg` say? I do not get any results

Comment: Babel tries to load `<language>.cfg` if existent. You probably have added `texmf-dist/doc/support/pedigree-perl/examples` to the `TEXINPUTS` variable in order to access the `.csv` files there, so `babel` finds `english.cfg` and wants to load it, but it's not a TeX file.

Comment: @egreg Ahh, I was looking for that one, but forgot to look inside `babel.def`

Comment: egreg you are right. I just put /usr/share// in TEXINPUTS. What should i put in there?

Comment: Just don't set `TEXINPUTS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have in your `TEXINPUTS` path a file called `english.cfg`; such a file is indeed existent in `<TeX-root>/doc/support/pedigree-perl/examples`, but it's a Perl file.

The `doc` subtree should never be added to the TeX search paths. Setting

```
export TEXINPUTS=/usr/share//:
```

is definitely a bad idea. There's usually no need to set the variable.