# Can I \usepackage with a full path?

Tags: packages, paths

As the name suggests - can I do something like:

`\usepackage{/home/nebffa/Desktop/maths/questions/fillwithlines.sty}`

LaTeX is throwing errors at me when I try to do it.

Comment: You should drop the `.sty`, but apart from that, there should be no problem. What kind of errors is LaTeX throwing your way?

Comment: @Werner L-l-l-legend! Dropping `.sty` fixed it. If you make your comment into an answer I will accept it

Comment: It is a syntax error to put a file path in the _name_ argument. Like many TeX errors it is possible to do it anyway and get some sort of result. but it is still an error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of using a full path, it is a much better practice to put your file in an appropriate place where TeX will find it. It seems you are a *NIX user, so you may try

```
$ less `kpsewhich texmf.cnf`
```

to know which places are these.  There is a lot of comments in this file, they will help you.  Alternatively, you can use the TEXMFHOME or the TEXINPUTS environment variable. Their use is detailed in `texmf.cnf`as well.

You probably want to distinguish three cases of use for your software package `mypackage`:

- *Site-wide installation,* it is then adapted to store your TeX files in a site-wide available directory and `${TEXMFLOCAL}/tex/latex/mypackage` is probably a good choice. (Use `kpsexpand` to know which actual path to use, as in `kpsexpand  '${TEXMFLOCAL}/tex/latex/mypackge'`).
- *User specific installation*, the directory `${TEXMFHOME}/tex/latex/mypackage` then looks appropriate.
- *Development,* while you are developing your package, you probably want to avoid repeteadly installing TeX related files and prefer add the appropriate locations to the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable.

The file `texmf.cnf` contains useful informations about these variables.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle is there another way to do this? I am writing a Python (programming) package and need to bundle my `.sty` file with the package.

Comment: @nebffa Then (to be portable) you really don't want to require users to put an absolute path in their latex document. You should just use `\usepackage{name}` and then stick `name.sty` anywhere on the tex input path, either the current directory or one of the standard places, or a new place that you add to the path.

Comment: @nebffa If you really want to input a file from a fixed location it is not (to latex) a package so just use `\input{/path/to/file.tex}` and put the macros in a `.tex` file (starting with `\makeatletter` if needed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well the user won't put in the absolute path, I do. But I see your point - what I should do is have Python add a specific folder to the TEXMFHOME environment variable, and then go from there, yes?

Comment: TeX use the k path search library to lookup files. It is documented in `info kpathsea`. If you are distributing a software package called `mypackage` installed system-wide, your files could go in `/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/mypackage` or a similar path (see `texmf.cnf` as I wrote in my answer).  If your package is installed for only one user, then your package should go in `$TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/mypackage` and `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME` tells you which values is actually considered. I would rather use the environment variable for engineering not for deployment.

Comment: You should incorporate your comment about the different `texmf` locations into your answer.  I suspect many people (don't know that they) are looking for the information contained in the comment.

Comment: @jon You are right, I edited my answer.

Comment: On my distribution `less \`kpsewhich texmf.cnf\`` only displays a very short document with "This texmf.cnf file should contain only your personal changes [...]".

Comment: @Annan It would have been useful to quote the name of your distribution, and why not a link towards a complete version of the file. There are chances that the file revealed by `less \`kpsewhich texmf.cnf\`` also explains how to find the main *distribution* `texmf.cnf` file.

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald Sorry, it's texlive on debian. "why not a link towards a complete version of the file", I would like to know where that is also! It says the full version is at ".../texlive/YYYY/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf" however this is relative to something.

Comment: Okay, I'm an idiot. `kpsewhich texmf.cnf` returns `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf.cnf` which contains the relative path to `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf`

Comment: If you set the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable you probably want to append a colon so that it's default value is appended instead of overridden. Without the colon my computer did not find pdflatex anymore. [[source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/93733/120953)]

Answer (score 26):

`\usepackage{<file>}` can take a full path, but requires you to drop the file extension. That is, it assumes `\usepackage{<path>/file}` will include `file.sty` located in `<path>`, self-appending the extension (known as `\@pkgextension`). So, drop the `.sty`.

The following MWE reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx.sty}
\begin{document} 
Test
\end{document}
```

yielding the error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `graphicx.sty.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or  to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
```

Comment: LaTeX issues a warning, if the package name in `\usepackage` does not match the package name in `\ProvidesPackage` of the package file: `LaTeX Warning: You have requested package "...", but the package provides "...".`

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek It does. And it is one of the most annoying things it does if you do `\usepackage{../mypkg}`

Comment: It is _wrong_ to use a full path and one of the main reasons of the `\ProvidesPackage` system is to warn users of that.