# Using style packages expkv-def.sty and expkv-opt.sty

Tags: options

I have `expkv-def.sty` and `expkv-opt.sty` stored in directory `expkv`.  How can I use the two packages from another `sty` file.

Currently I have the following `ephram.sty`

```latex
    \ProvidesPackage{ephram}[2022/04/25 Ephram Document Style]
    
    \RequirePackage{expkv-opt,expkv-def}
    \ekvdefinekeys{ephram}
      {
        choice-enum paper = \ephram@paper {21, a4, b5}
      }
    \ekvoProcessLocalOptions{ephram}
    
    \RequirePackage{geometry}
    \ifcase\ephram@paper
      \geometry{paperheight=21cm, paperwidth=21cm}
    \or
      \geometry{a4paper}
    \or
      \geometry{b5paper}
    \fi
```

Comment: You could use full directory path (`c:/Users/[User]/Documents/CustomSty/expkv-opt.sty` etc) or you could use the answer [to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/641930/245306) to put it in your Latex search folder. Which operating system are you using? I am on windows so may not be able to help

Comment: Have put the directory path.  The `sty` files are now getting assessed.

Comment: Perfect, I will add an answer so this question doesn't get bumped to the top every few months by the `community bot` if it doesn't have answers, glad to help with your recent questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `.sty` files, the full directory path can be added or the package can be installed into the `Latex` search directory (provided by [Skillmon in a previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/641930/245306)).

In this case, setting the full directory path e.g. `c:/Users/[User]/Documents/CustomSty/expkv-opt.sty` can allow the packages to be directly located. It would probably be best to use the method by Skillmon so that `\usepackage{expkv-opt}` could be used universally on your system, but if you do not mind typing the full path, then putting the full directory path is a good alternative.