# Directory for storing .sty not where it was supposed to be

Tags: packages, installing, tex-core, texmf

I have the same problem as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te), but since it's too old I guess it is better to open a new question than to wait for clarification in a 7 years old answer.

I have a .sty file with stuff I want to use, and I'm trying to find the correct directory to put the .sty file, following Stefan's answer in the linked question. When I call

`kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME`

I get `/home/terek/texmf`, as predicted. There is no such directory *here* (even when I show hidden files). Several other similar questions and answers (such as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93712/definition-of-the-texinputs-variable)) mention a directory like `~/texmf/tex/latex/something/`. Am I supposed to **create** that directory?

Searching, I have a bunch of other "texmf" directories, and I don't have a clue of what is the correct one, so see for yourself:

[image]

Bear in mind that I am a beginner linux user, and I'll likely ask for silly clarifications. I am also aware that the question title isn't very informative, but I am so lost that I can't think of anything better, so feel free to edit it if you want.

Comment: Normally you should have  `texmf-local` directory, which is the place to store the files not in the distribution that are available to any user of your computer. Of course you have te organise these files according to the T.D.S., say `texmf-local/tex/latex/foo/foo.sty`, and if you have a documentation it should be in `texmf-local/doc/latex/foo/foo.pdf`.

Comment: @Bernard There is no `texmf-local` directory here. And I don't know what T.D.S. is, either. But thanks for the attention

Comment: T.D.S. is an acronym for TeX Directory Structure. It's strange you don't have a local root. You can create one. It should be installed in the same directory as the main `texmf`.

Comment: Ah, ok. But how can I know which `texmf` is the main one?

Comment: It should be `texmf-dist`. You'll have more details in the [TeX Live user guide](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-110002.3).

Comment: @Bernard Not necessarily. Linux distros would put the main tree under `/usr/share` or something like that, but the local one under `/usr/local/texmf` or something. In this scenario, the local tree should **not** be located in the same directory as the main tree, as the main tree is in a directory managed by the package manager and the local tree ought not to be.

Comment: If you just want to use the `.sty` file yourself. If it is personal to you, especially if it is being edited for you by you, put it in the home tree. `mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/<name of package>/` and put the `.sty` file there.

Comment: @Bernard In this case, indeed, the main tree is in `/usr/share`, whereas the local tree is in `/usr/local/share`. And there is no main tree in the usual TDS sense, as it has been split up and different parts are in different places.

Comment: @cfr: I should update my information! I must say I haven't touched upon these details for years.

Comment: This is perfect, everything seems to work fine now!

Comment: @IvoTerek Whose instructions did you use? ;)

Comment: I created a directory `texmf` in my home, then inside it a `tex`, and yet inside a `latex`. Then I put my `terek.sty` in there and done. I assumed that `mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/<name of package>/` would have the same effect. Right?

Comment: Basically, yes. But it would be better to make a `terek` directory and put the file inside it inside `latex` inside `tex` inside `texmf` inside your home.

Comment: Ah, one more "layer"? Ok. Just for curiosity, why is it better? (if it is too complicated for a comment you can leave it, or summarize all in an answer, I'll accept it gladly)

Comment: It isn't better technically. But it is the standard layout. Hence, it makes the file's location predictable. It 'fits'. It makes things easier to understand for people. TeX will find it anyway, but sometimes packages have multiple files here - several `.sty`s or a combination of a `.sty` and other files. If you have packages A and B, all of package A's files are in `tex/latex/A/` and all of B's in `tex/latex/B/` etc. So you can see immediately which package a file belongs to and which LaTeX files a package provides. If A provides e.g. fonts, these will be in e.g. `fonts/.../A/` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For TeX Live, manually installed files should be located in one of two trees (in the standard case).

The basic idea is that there are (er ... roughly) three trees. The `MAIN` tree is handled by TeX Live's package manager (for an upstream install) or your Linux distro's package manager (for a repackaged install). You should not add, modify or remove files in this tree at all by hand.

The second is the `LOCAL` tree. This is for packages installed locally for all users. Its location is given by

```
kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL
```

The third is the `HOME` tree. This is for personal single-user packages. Its location is given by

```
kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME
```

However, **font support packages should NEVER<sup>1</sup> be installed into `TEXMFHOME` but ALWAYS<sup>1</sup> into `TEXMFLOCAL`** even on single-user systems. Undoing this is more complex than never doing it, because merely uninstalling and installing into the right place doesn't undo the damage.

Once you know which tree you are using, you need to figure out where in that tree to put the files. For LaTeX packages, `.sty` files must end up somewhere under `<root of tree>/tex/latex/` but preferably under `<root of tree>/tex/latex/<name of package>/` as this helps keep your tree intelligible by human beings. Likewise, documentation goes under `<root of tree>/doc/latex/<name of package>/`. You can usually see where things belong by looking at the structure under `TEXMFMAIN` and mirroring the hierarchy below the root.

Most files, including `.sty` files can also be included in your working directory - wherever your `.tex` is - and will be found without messing around with the tree structure issue at all.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>As with most such rules, this may be broken if you really know what you're doing and why you are doing it. However, the only case in which you might reasonably consider doing this, albeit with a heavy heart, is one in which you lack authorisation to modify the `LOCAL` tree and have been unsuccessful in prolonged efforts to persuade the administrator of your local TeX installation to install the font packages of your dreams. Even then, the sensible course will generally be to forgo the fonts concerned. 'I prefer it' is inadequate. 'My report requires a symbol not otherwise available to me at all and my report represents a major life project or has substantial social, moral or cultural value' might be good enough, but probably it is easier to change your life goals and/or society's values.</sub>