# Own sty files, maintenance and portability

Tags: packages

As you easily note, I am new here and english is not my first language: so, be gentle please.

I am using a windows 7 machine with MiKTeX installed (just in case).

I have the following directory structure (in a pendrive, named `D` in my system):

```
D:\step\foot1\shoe1  
D:\step\foot1\shoe2  
D:\step\foot2  
D:\step\styles
```

I have created the file finger.sty in the fourth folder and I have tex files in the first three folders: I want to use `finger.sty` file (via `\usepackage`) in those tex files.

For portability reasons, I want to use the folder `\step` in different machines with different TeX directories structures (I don't want to touch them) and, possibly, naming my pendrive with different letters.

For maintenance reasons, I don't want to have a copy of `finger.sty` file anywhere but the fourth folder.

How could it be possible to satisfy all my requirements (wishes)?

Comment: You can use relative paths like `\usepackage{../../styles/finger}`. Note that you will probably get a warning about `You requested '../../styles/finger.sty' but the package provides 'finger.sty'` but as far as I know you can safely ignore them.

Comment: MikTeX uses a filename database (FNDB) for .sty files.  You need to load your directory using the console settings->directories, then renew the FNDB to access the .sty file.

Comment: You can place it anywhere and use a make script that [sets an extended `TEXINPUTS` variable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93712/definition-of-the-texinputs-variable)

Answer (score 4):

Put your `finger.sty` in

```
D:\step\styles\tex\latex\juan\finger.sty
```

Then go to the miktex console and in `settings->directories` add `D:\step\styles` as a new root.

Alternatively run on a terminal

```
initexmf register-root D:\step\styles
```

When you are on another machine you can activate the styles folder there in a similar way.

Comment: I can not change anything on other machines I use: that is why I have to fulfill this requirement.