# How to convert Latex folder(combination of .tex, .png, .bbl etc.) into pdf using terminal?

Tags: pdftex

I have a folder which contains one latex file, few images(in .png as well as .pdf format). I want to convert this whole folder into a pdf file similar to what overleaf does. I want to use a terminal command as I have to do this for thousands of file. I want to run these commands in python. I used "pdflatex arxiv.tex" after going into that folder(from terminal) and it works fine. But when I run the command "pdflatex ~/path/to/folder/arxiv.tex" then it shows that the error that other files(.png, .bbl)  are not present?

Comment: First thing you have to put into your mind: Do never use spaces in file names and paths.

Comment: I didn't use it in my local system. Just added here by mistake

Comment: AFAIK LaTeX usually resolves (local) file inclusions from the current working directory. So if you are in `~/path/to/folder` and call `pdflatex arxiv.tex` everything is fine, but if you are in, say `~` and call `pdflatex ~/path/to/folder/arxiv.tex` the files are not found. You can work around this by setting `TEXINPUTS` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/93712/35864) or the like. If you have to run additional tools (BibTeX, makeindex, ...) you may have to do a similar thing with those as well. That's why I would just try to run all tools from within the right folder and be done with it. ...

Comment: ... Is there any reason why you want to say `pdflatex ~/path/to/folder/arxiv.tex` and not `cd ~/path/to/folder/` and `pdflatex arxiv.tex`? Note that it may or may not be enough to run `pdflatex` just once (especially if things changed in the file since the last run), in cases like this automatic tools like `latexmk` can be useful.