# \input a file that exists either in "./" or in "./figures"

Tags: programming

I use XFig to draw most of my figures (how old am I?) and I find convenient to export in "LaTeX+PDF" format, in which a simple LaTeX source. e.g., `fig03.pdf_t` (the extension is fixed), is created. That file takes care of typesetting, using the document settings, and uses `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package to include, in our example, the file `fig03.pdf` in a `picture` environment.

I usually have the XFig sources and the exported files in a `./figures` sub-directory and I have `\graphicspath{{figures/}}` in the document source.

So far … but sometimes I like to put in evidence, in the document directory, a particular figure or I'm just lazy or confused and some of my figures are in `./` rather than in `./figures/`.

I'd like to be able to write

```
\input\get{fig03}
```

and have LaTeX find the file for me.

How do I define the `\get` command?

---

In its most basic formulation `\get` just scans `./` and `./figures/` but it seems reasonable that this can be customized setting a list in the way of `\graphicspath`

Comment: If (for instance) `foo.png` is in the `figures` subdirectory and `bar.png` is in the current directory, `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{{figures/}}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{foo}
\includegraphics{bar}

\end{document}` finds both files.

Comment: @frougon Yes, `\includegraphics` finds both but I'm using, I have to use `\input` to read into my document the LaTeX source prepared by XFig

Comment: Workaround: Export xfig figures to `tikz` or `pict2e`, (the latter cannot do hatches), and only `input` one file (input{fig03.tikz}), or copy-paste the entire file into the latex document. The tikz-output is superior to latex+pdf output. Also, did you have a look at the `import` package, which provides some search-path setting machinery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\get}[1]{%
\IfFileExists{./figures/#1}{%
        \input{./figures/#1} 
    }{%
        \input{./#1} 
    }
}


\begin{document}

\get{fig03.pdf_t}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can afford to modify the environment only for compiling this kind of document, one possibility is to add the needed directories to `TEXINPUTS` (see for instance [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/93712/73317)). Otherwise, in order to have your customizable list of paths to search, you can use the following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_gboffi_search_path_seq

\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_if_eq:nn { x } { T, F, TF }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \gboffi_set_search_path:n #1
  {
    \seq_gclear:N \g_gboffi_search_path_seq
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#1}
      {
        % Append a '/' if not already present before appending a path to
        % \g_gboffi_search_path_seq.
        \str_if_eq:xnTF { \tl_item:nn {##1} { -1 } } { / }
          { \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_gboffi_search_path_seq {##1} }
          { \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_gboffi_search_path_seq {##1/} }
      }
  }

\msg_new:nnn { gboffi } { cannot-find-file }
  { Can't~find~file~'\exp_not:n {#1}.tex'. }

\bool_new:N \l__gboffi_found_flag_bool

\cs_new_protected:Npn \gboffi_input:n #1
  {
    \bool_set_false:N \l__gboffi_found_flag_bool

    \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_gboffi_search_path_seq
      {
        \file_if_exist:nT { ##1#1.tex }
          {
            \file_input:n { ##1#1.tex }
            \bool_set_true:N \l__gboffi_found_flag_bool
            \seq_map_break:
          }
      }

    \bool_if:NF \l__gboffi_found_flag_bool
      { \msg_error:nnn { gboffi } { cannot-find-file } {#1} }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \myInputWithSearchPath { m }
  {
    \gboffi_input:n {#1}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \mySetSearchPath { m }
  {
    \gboffi_set_search_path:n {#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \mySetSearchPath{., figures dir 1, {path, with, commas}, figures dir 2}

  \myInputWithSearchPath{fig01}\par
  \myInputWithSearchPath{fig02}\par
  \myInputWithSearchPath{fig03}\par
  \myInputWithSearchPath{fig04}

  % This would print “Package gboffi Error: Can't find file 'non-existent.tex'.”
  % \myInputWithSearchPath{non-existent}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

I let you replace `.tex` with `.pdf_t` or whatever file extension you want to use. There are two places involved:

- in the definition of `\gboffi_input:n`, where it reads `\file_if_exist:nT { ##1#1.tex }` and `\file_input:n { ##1#1.tex }`;
- in the error message printed for non-existent files:

  ```latex
  \msg_new:nnn { gboffi } { cannot-find-file }
    { Can't~find~file~'\exp_not:n {#1}.tex'. }
  ```

Comment: Oops, maybe after all I do not want a customizable list of paths...  On the other hand, I wonder if such a machinery could not be the core of a package, `\usepackage{searchpath}\newsearch{fig}\figpath{{...},{...},{...}}` and later `\input\figsearch{fig03.pdf_t}`

Comment: You should do `\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_if_eq:nn { e } { T,F,TF,p }` so the conditional remains expandable. On the other hand, `\str_if_eq:ee(TF)` are already provided and expanding both arguments in the particular case is not a problem.

Comment: @egreg I've replaced the `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_if_eq:nnTF { x }` with `\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_if_eq:nn { x } { p, T, F, TF }`, thanks for the reminder (the fact that `\str_if_eq:xnT` is not expandable isn't a problem here). For now, I prefer using `x` variants over `e` ones when there is no downside, because some people have very old installations where `e` variants are very slow.

Comment: @gboffi If you didn't need a customizable list of paths, why did you write “it seems reasonable that this can be customized setting a list in the way of `\graphicspath`” in your question?

Comment: Because it's a nice feature and because I did not imagine that the solution could be so much over my head...

Comment: @gboffi The code simply implements the obvious algorithm, caring about appending a trailing `/` to a path only when necessary. It is not because `expl3` code uses normal spacing for a programming language, which TeX doesn't, that it is more difficult. I could put all this on a single line. Some people would probably upvote because it would be short and they wouldn't understand anything. That wouldn't make it good programming, though (i.e.: readable, without bad surprises, maintainable).

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your edit! Indeed, I had included generation of the predicate by mistake when adding the `\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn`.