# include own *.sty file when running from command line

Tags: pdftex, packages, windows, python

I am running `pdflatex` from inside the python script. Python project is inside `venv` and my terminal command is like `abs\path\to\pdflatex.exe abs\path\to\file.tex` but when run, it cannot find my *.sty file which is placed in the same directory as my main .tex file. Program waits for me to enter the path to that sty file. I need this to be automatically done by running the command inside python script.  How can I fix this?

Comment: it is usually better to make the script cd to the directory with the document then do `pdflatex file`  any  relative paths in the file are relative to the working directory of the pdflatex process not relative to the main document. If you cd first then these are the same and the result is a lot less confusing.

Comment: David's answer is definitely the preferred one; but if you are somehow constrained, then you can get around this by setting environmental variables. [TEXINPUTS does exist for a reason](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93712/definition-of-the-texinputs-variable).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, man! that was great, yet simple solution! I decided to make it that way, but then I saw `-include-directory` option and used it to make it one line command

Comment: @WillieWong I'm going to perform pdf generation on a daily basis and each time new directory with the current date and new content is created. and all files are slightly modified. So, `TEXINPUTS` won't be a good solution, I guess

Comment: @mend4x: you can set environmental variables dynamically **in your script**.